# Will iPhone 6 cost you $649 over two years?

Tags: iphone

After reading [this](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/09/19/true-cost-of-the-iphone-6/) page online, I got stunned, please go through the link, you will find that it says:

> While Apple and the major wireless carriers usually advertise the iPhone 6′s $199 price, that’s just the starting price for those that are signing up for a two-year contract and are eligible for an upgrade. The full retail price for the 16GB iPhone 6 is actually $649 and a lot of people are going to spend that much or more either upfront or through a payment scheme like Verizon Edge, which is essentially a payment plan that spreads the $649 cost over 20 months and allows subscribers to upgrade to the next generation iPhone after just a year.

My question is, is it a good idea to use a payment scheme like Verizon Edge with the iPhone 6?

Comment: Not necessary, it is a choice. As always, if you have the cash buy it up front.

Answer (score 2):

> Verizon Edge is a program that provides you the flexibility to upgrade
>   early, and pay for your device over 20 months rather than paying for
>   it all upfront. You’ll make a monthly payment until your device is
>   paid off.
>
> After 30 days, **if you’ve paid at least 60% of the Edge device**,
>   you’ll have the option to Edge Up to a new device without any upgrade
>   fees.

What does it mean?

You will have a 2 Years contract with Verizon and have to pay the additional Verizon service costs (phone+Data). Now each time you Edge up to next phone the clock starts all over again. (2 Years contract).

The only benefit is you do not have to spend the cost of the iPhone up front, but over 2 Years, and the ability to get a newer model.

For Verizon you will pay >$60/M for network services. With some other providers you will pay $40/M for about the same services.  Difference of 720/480 is $240 per Year that you pay more.

So you actual cost after 2 Year with Verizon is 649+720+720 =$2089, while direct buy will cost you 649+480+480= $1609.